# TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 23.254945875326612 of type <class 'numpy.float64'>

Tags: python, numpy

```
round((df_Webinar['A'].isnull().sum()/(df_Webinar['A'].shape[0]))*100,2)
```

Above line of code is giving me below error

TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 0.23254945875326613 of type <class 'numpy.float64'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

I am expecting result to be 23.25 but getting error as mentioned

Comment: Is that the entire code? Or might the error be on another line? When posting an error, you should show the entire stack trace.

Comment: this is the entire piece of code which is giving me error.The code works perfectly fine when I write   (df_Webinar['A'].isnull().sum()/(df_Webinar['A'].shape[0]))*100  but when I add in round() to limit places after decimals then it throws me error

Comment: Did you rebind the name `round` to some object somewhere in your code?

Comment: It seems like this error message is from PySpark. Are you using `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`?  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66604197/6394617)

Comment: @Pranav167 show the dataframe so we can reproduce the error.