Pandas UDF to derive new column
In Spark/Databricks, I have a pandas dataframe with a string column. I need to perform multiple actions on this column (data cleansing type stuff), and produce a new column from the result.
Here's my current (stripped down) function:
@pandas_udf('string')
def pandaFunction(text):
  str = <do lots of clever things to text>
  return str

I am attempting to call it like so:
pandasDF['newColumn'] = pandaFunction(pandasDF['oldColumn']

This fails with TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column:
I'm a long way from a pyspark or pandas expert.  I've been googling all morning, but no luck so far.  What am I doing wrong here?

is it a pandas on spark dataframe? or just pandas dataframe?

On Spark sorry.

convert pandas dataframe to spark and create a udf in spark and try to use that udf :https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html

try something like this

# Define a Python function to be used as a UDF
@udf
def my_custom_function(x):
    return f"value_{x}"

# Convert pandas-on-Spark DataFrame to Spark DataFrame
sdf = psdf.to_spark()

# Add new column using UDF
sdf = sdf.withColumn('new_column', my_custom_function(sdf['old_column']))

# Convert back to pandas-on-Spark DataFrame if needed
psdf_with_new_column = sdf.pandas_api()


I get the exact same error :(

in that case you'll have to convert pandas-on-spark dataframe to pyspark dataframe then use udf to add a column and then convert back to pandas-on-spark dataframe(solution edited)

also you might be getting this error due to discrepancy in some other part of your code
see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54344137/pyspark-program-is-throwing-error-typeerror-invalid-argument-not-a-string-or
